# Client computer unable to join active directory domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a local network consisting of 2 computers. The network configuration is as in the below picture.

[image]

On **DC01** I installed Windows Server 2012 R2. On **Laptop01** I have windows 8 enterprise. I have turned on "AD DS" and "DNS" roles on the server (**DC01**).

IP configuration of the network:

```
ADSL:     192.168.1.1

DC01:     192.168.1.10 Preferred DNS: 127.0.0.1

Laptop01: 192.168.1.11 Preferred DNS: 192.168.1.10
```

I created a domain `mib.com`. Here is result of pinging it from **Laptop01**.

[image]

Now I am trying to join **Laptop01** to this domain but getting an error

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

**Update**

Result of DCDIAG

[image]

---

**Update 2**

DNS manager screenshot

[image]

Comment: So you installed the AD DS and DNS roles on DC01 and created an AD domain named `mib.com`? Have you verified that the relevant SRV records are registered in the DNS zone for mib.com?

Comment: DC01 should use 192.168.1.10 for primary DNS and 127.0.0.1 for secondary DNS.

Comment: Run the AD DS and DNS Best Practice Analyzer's on DC01. Run DCDIAG on DC01.

Comment: @joeqwerty `DC01 should use 192.168.1.10 for primary DNS and 127.0.0.1 for secondary DNS.` -> didn't work

Comment: @joeqwerty, Please see the update regarding DCDIAG

Comment: @joeqwerty, Please see the update regarding SRV records

Comment: Your DNS zone doesn't look right. Why do you have a NS for the zone named `mib.com`? Also, show us thew _msdcs zone and the SRV records in that zone.

Comment: @joeqwerty, `Why do you have a NS for the zone named mib.com?` That NS was added automatically when I installed Active Directory domain

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pictures.  Makes this much easier to troubleshoot.
Your domain is "MIB.com"  - NOT "MIB"

Put that in the Computer Name/Domain Changes window,

try that again, and let me know.

Comment: Getting Error:

`An Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain "MIB.com" could not be contacted.

Ensure that the domain name is typed correctly.`

Comment: You can join a domain using either the NetBIOS name of the domain or the FQDN. See my answer here for how name resolution during the domain join process works. - https://serverfault.com/questions/717689/cannot-join-client-to-domain-non-virtual-dns-issue/717914#717914

Answer (score 0):

Your DC is resolving to an IPv6 address for some reason. Since that address is not working for DCDIAG, it's not going to work for clients either.

Unbind IPv6 from your network adapter(s) on the DC. Double-check the IPv4 address to ensure it is correct. Restart the NETLOGON service, then restart the DNS service.

After that, either clear the DNS cache on the client or reboot it. Try to join the domain again.

Comment: I disabled Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6) on both `DC01` and `Laptop01` long before creating Active Directory domain

Comment: That's not an IPv6 record. It's the DsaCname Record for the DC for non-SRV aware clients. There's one DsaCname Record for each DC. **DO NOT DISABLE IPv6!**

Comment: @joeqwerty, Enabling IPv6 didn't help.

Comment: Looks like problem is in DNS zone configuration,

Comment: Right. I didn't say it was going to fix the problem. I only meant that you should not disable it.