# Why does adding to 'domain' without .local work?

Tags: domain

Just a query - we have an on-prem Windows 2012R2 server running AD with 'domain.local'. I've always added the computers to the domain using 'domain.local', however my assistant tells me that he's always added them using just 'domain' until today when it didn't work, but using 'domain.local' did.

Why would adding them as 'domain' work at all?

Thanks

Comment: See my answer here - https://serverfault.com/questions/717689/cannot-join-client-to-domain-non-virtual-dns-issue/717914#717914

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks for the response. That makes sense as to why it works without the DNS suffix, but turning that on it's head then, what would be the possible reason for it not working without the DNS suffix as we found today?

Comment: Without a DNS suffix, the client will use a NetBIOS broadcast to locate a Domain Controller. So my guess is the client is not getting a reply to the NetBIOS broadcast. Is this client remote by any chance and connected to the corporate network via a VPN? Is the client on a different routed network from the Domain Controller?

Comment: No, client is on prem, wired single network.